# Maximum length of a domain name without the http://www. & .com parts

Tags: url, dns, max

What is the maximum length of the 'name' part in a domain?
I'm referring to the `google` in `http://www.google.com`. How long can the `google` part be without what's before and after it?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Each label may contain up to 63 characters.

Comment: yes, technically called labels and it may contain up to 63 characters. Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System

Comment: Thanks for that straight forward answer.

Comment: Part of the reasoning behind 63 (vs 255) is for packet compression.  a 1,1 in the first 2 bits of an 8 bit length indicates a pointer to a previous label (which _should_actually_ make the limit 191)  Some poor implementation that checked those bits as individual flags is probably the reason for 63 char limit.

Comment: Take in consideration that domains can be nested, for example: `www.group-of-hosts.department.example.com` - So each label may be 63 chars long and the full domain without `www.` and `.com` could be longer, as in this case it would be `group-of-hosts.department.example` - This may be longer than 63.

Comment: from same wiki source: `The full domain name may not exceed the length of 253 characters in its textual representation.` So i assume it's safe to use 255 length varchar to save domain name while using sql db.

Answer (score 29):

"URI producers should use names
that conform to the DNS syntax, even when use of DNS is not
immediately apparent, and should limit these names to no more than
255 characters in length."

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986

"The DNS itself places only one restriction on the particular labels
that can be used to identify resource records.  That one restriction
relates to the length of the label and the full name.  The length of
any one label is limited to between 1 and 63 octets.  A full domain
name is limited to 255 octets (including the separators)."

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2181

Comment: Hostname is 255. Domain name is 253

Comment: ...with or without the separators?

Answer (score 17):

The full domain name may not exceed a total length of 253 characters in its external dotted-label specification.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System

If you are getting anywhere close to 253 characters, I think you should look for a shorter domain name...

Comment: Actually, I want to put that number into a regular expression.

Comment: Obviously if your domain name is approaching 253 chars it should be shorter ... but have you heard of this thing called ... the internet? People are crazy there. You can't imagine some of the things they come up with.

Answer (score 11):

## TLDR Answer

Use these limits:

> Labels: **`61`** octets.
>
> Names: **`253`** octets.

Many applications will work even if you exceed these limits (like Gmail), but there are many older applications that will not.

## Source

**[RFC1035: Domain Names - Implementation And Specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035)** (published November 1987), an accepted [Internet Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Standard#:%7E:text=An%20Internet%20Standard%20is%20characterized,that%20was%20discontinued%20in%202011.),  gives the following limits to subdomains and to the entire domain length when viewed in a browser...

> Various objects and parameters in the DNS have size limits.  They are
> listed below.  Some could be easily changed, others are more
> fundamental.
>
> labels          `63` octets [bytes/characters] or less
>
> names           `255` octets [bytes/characters] or less

The working level of these are:

- Labels: **`61`** octets.
- Names: **`253`** octets.

That's because [**`RFC821`**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc821) (published August 1982) defines emails in the format of `user@domain.com`, and the smallest value for `user` would be one character.  That leaves one character for `@`, and then you only have `253` characters left for the `domain.com` part.

This was reconfirmed numerous times...

- [**RFC2181: Clarifications to the DNS Specification**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2181) (published July 1997) : Only a proposed standard. *"A full domain name is limited to 255 octets (including the separators)."*
- [**RFC3986: Uniform Resource Identifier (URI): Generic Syntax**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) (published January 2005) : Accepted Internet standard.  *"URI producers should use names that conform to the DNS syntax, even when use of DNS is not immediately apparent, and should limit these names to no more than 255 characters in length."*
- [**RFC5321: Simple Mail Transfer Protocol**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321) (published October 2008) : Only a proposed standard.  This RFC gives the max length of label or subdomains to be `64`, one more than the others of `63`.  I recommend sticking with `63`.  *"The maximum total length of a domain name or number is 255 octets."*

You may have 63 characters per label (or subdomain) and 255 characters per name (this includes the TLD).

Notice that it gives the definition in *octets*.  That's because it's looking at physical bytes, not literal bytes.  For instance, `\.` is interpreted as `.` (one literal byte), because the `\` escapes it, but it is encoded as `\.` (two physical bytes).  These octet limits are physical byte limits.

Answer (score 8):

As a demonstration, this website has a 63 characters domain name, the maximum allowed:
http://63-characters-is-the-longest-possible-domain-name-for-a-website.com

Comment: The site is down but here is the archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20160308231823/http://63-characters-is-the-longest-possible-domain-name-for-a-website.com