# Getting 502 proxy error while trying to write rewriterule

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, proxypass

I have a domain int.business.com. When I hit this I want the browser to show the contents in the domain www.data.business.com but the users should still see int.business.com in the address bar. Here is my vhost configuration

```
RewriteEngine on
SSLProxyEngine on 
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ int.business.com [P]
ProxyPassReverse / data.newbusiness.com
```

With this configuration, I am getting a 502 proxy error

```
Proxy Error
The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request GET /.

Reason: Error reading from remote server
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You should modify your configuration like this:

```
ProxyPass        "/" "http://www.data.business.com"
ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://www.data.business.com"
```

The first argument is what you want to proxy, the second is the target of that  proxy.

The `SSLProxyEngine` is not required, since you do not proxy to SSL anyway.

Doing a proxy with `RewriteRule` works, but performance is better with ProxyPass (due to persistent connections).  See: 
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p for more details.

Also, you do not use any complicated regex here, so this is sufficient.

Make sure you load modules mod_proxy, mod_proxy_http.

Comment: I tried the above configuration. My actual domain is very long. So when I made the changes and trying to restart apache, the name is too long and it is trying to truncate it. I am not sure why.

Comment: See this for the limits on domain names lengths: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14402407/maximum-length-of-a-domain-name-without-the-http-www-com-parts

Comment: Or this: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limitrequestline and http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limitrequestfieldsize, which are configurable (no need to recompile your Apache).